# ant doesnt get the library dependencies

Tags: windows, maven, ant

My system: Windows 7
Ant Version: 1.8.2
JDK: 1.6.27 x64

Sorry Im starting to work with ant and currently trying to install it properly.

When I type in cmd this command:

```
ant -f fetch.xml -Ddest=system
```

to get the library dependencies, according official documentation I get following errors:

```
jspc:
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: tomcat/jasper-compiler/4.1.36/jasper-compil
er-4.1.36.pom
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] Unable to get resource from repository remote
(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: tomcat/jasper-compiler/4.1.36/jasper-compil
er-4.1.36.pom
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] Unable to get resource from repository central
 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: tomcat/jasper-runtime/4.1.36/jasper-runtime
-4.1.36.pom
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] Unable to get resource from repository remote
(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: tomcat/jasper-runtime/4.1.36/jasper-runtime
-4.1.36.pom
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] Unable to get resource from repository central
 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

jai:
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: javax/media/jai-core/1.1.3/jai-core-1.1.3.p
om
[artifact:dependencies] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifac
t tasks.
[artifact:dependencies]  Diagnosis:
[artifact:dependencies]
[artifact:dependencies] Unable to resolve artifact: Unable to get dependency inf
ormation: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'javax.media:jai-core:ja
r': Error getting POM for 'javax.media:jai-core' from the repository: Error tran
sferring file
[artifact:dependencies]   javax.media:jai-core:pom:1.1.3
[artifact:dependencies]
[artifact:dependencies] from the specified remote repositories:
[artifact:dependencies]   remote (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2),
[artifact:dependencies]   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[artifact:dependencies]
[artifact:dependencies]   javax.media:jai-core:jar:1.1.3
[artifact:dependencies]
[artifact:dependencies] from the specified remote repositories:
[artifact:dependencies]   remote (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2),
[artifact:dependencies]   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[artifact:dependencies] Path to dependency:
[artifact:dependencies]         1) unspecified:unspecified:jar:0.0
[artifact:dependencies]
[artifact:dependencies]
[artifact:dependencies] Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://
repository.jboss.org/maven2/javax/media/jai-core/1.1.3/jai-core-1.1.3.pom
[artifact:dependencies]

BUILD FAILED
D:\work\ant_182\fetch.xml:309: The following error occurred while executing this
 line:
D:\work\ant_182\fetch.xml:116: Unable to resolve artifact: Unable to get depende
ncy information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'javax.media:jai-
core:jar': Error getting POM for 'javax.media:jai-core' from the repository: Err
or transferring file
  javax.media:jai-core:pom:1.1.3

from the specified remote repositories:
  remote (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

  javax.media:jai-core:jar:1.1.3

from the specified remote repositories:
  remote (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Path to dependency:
        1) unspecified:unspecified:jar:0.0



Total time: 4 seconds
```

I tried to google and cant find any suitable solution, except that **jasper-runtime
    -4.1.36.pom** is not available in repository. 
Can anybody point me out how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but for those looking for a solution, this page explains it concisely:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-notifications/201112.mbox/%3Cbug-52374-48744@https.issues.apache.org/bugzilla/%3E

Answer (score 0):

It seems that maven is not accessible from your build machine. 
Can you use a browser on the build machine and see if you can access http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ ?

Comment: when i go http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ at browser i get this: "Browsing for this directory has been disabled.

View this directory's contents on http://search.maven.org instead." And http://search.maven.org works! So should I replace repository?

Comment: Try to download the dependency by hand: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/tomcat/jasper-compiler/4.1.36/jasper-compiler-4.1.36.pom

Comment: I cant - I get 404 error

Comment: HTTP 404 means that the jasper-compiler-4.1.36.pom can not be found at that path/URL. Try to find a different version that is working and update the ant script, or find the right path/URL.